# Cisco router cannot ping its own up interface

Tags: cisco, router

I have been troubleshooting using `ping` on both 2600 and 3700 series Cisco routers. The `ping` is done on interfaces that have status of `up`, line protocol `up`. On FastEthernet interfaces, if status is `up` and line protocol is `up`, the router can successfully ping the ip address of its own FastEthernet interface. For Serial interfaces, if status is `up` and line protocol is `up`, in some cases the router cannot ping its own serial interface IP address.

Can someone give any explanation as to why a ping on the router's own interface should fail for a Serial interface in  an `up/up` state?

```
R4#show ip interface brief
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
FastEthernet0/0            192.168.10.1    YES NVRAM  up                    up
Serial0/0                  192.168.1.2     YES NVRAM  up                    up
FastEthernet0/1            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
Serial0/1                  192.168.4.1     YES NVRAM  up                    up
R4#ping 192.168.1.2

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.1.2, timeout is 2 seconds:
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the serial interfaces frame-relay?  If so, you'll need to map the local interface IP to one of the active DLCIs in order to ping the interface.

```
interface Serial0/0
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 frame-relay map ip 192.168.0.2 102 broadcast
 frame-relay map ip 192.168.0.1 102
```

Comment: They are all PPP. All router interfaces are configured `encapsulation ppp`

Comment: Any of them PPPoE?  I've seem some issues with pinging the local dialer/virtual-template interface for an up/up interface.  Can you give us the full router config and specify the ping that doesn't work (via pastebin)?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hJCjn07f

Comment: the output I get at the terminal is in the EDIT.

Comment: I've seen instances where PPP interfaces are up/up but they are failing negotiation in some other way, which doesn't allow the interface to become functional.  Is this on real hardware or a emulator?  What does the other end's interface look like?  Does the remote router show up as a CDP neighbor?